# Justify NavBar only when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to justify a navbar once collapsed?

Currently I have a navbar that floats to the right but once it collapses I want it to become justified.

Ive tried the following with no luck

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    float:none;
}
}
```

As you can see in the picture, the collapsed menu items are on a new line, which would have happened if it was justified initially.

http://imgur.com/fP6WcOt

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle highlighting the problem? It's hard to identify the problem without context.

Comment: Image only helps a little. We need to see some HTML and more CSS.

Comment: Yeah, have you ever used jsFiddle or something along those lines? Here is an example that shows using bootstrap wih it: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ If you could put your HTML/CSS/etc in there, it would really help us help you.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else